# How to set up Android CTS in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-source, android-cts

How should I set up Android CTS in Eclipse?

I have tried to follow the guide at [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-development.html) for setting up CTS development in Eclipse. However, I get build errors when trying to set it up in Eclipse Indigo with android-2.3.7_r1 on Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64.

Eclipse refuses to build the project due to missing libraries. When these libraries are removed from the build path it still won't build, due to several hundred or so missing imports (for example `import android.annotation.cts.Profile;`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem during the instantiation of AOSP in Eclipse. javalib.jar for google-common_intermediates was missing and the second javalib.jar was also missing. In this case I simply removed the second library from the build path and the first library was simply renamed to android-common_intermediates. Maybe in your case, there are also some renamings?